# Position Relative to the window

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I have a Tumblr account and I'm working on editing the html of it. My question is this: how do I make my side bar be in a certain position but then I scroll down on the page, it stays where it is relative to my browser? For an example of what I'm talking about, click "ask a question" and look at "similar questions" then scroll. I would prefer for it to be in CSS. I have already tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

set the elements css `position` attribute to `fixed` and user `top`/`left` and `margin` to place it where you want it to be. Like so:

```
#sideBar {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

The above code would vertically center a `200px` high div and place it `10px` from the left hand border.

**UPDATE**

This example will show you how to achieve what you're after!
[Demo with jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/E38U8/1/)

**Update (1)**

The following jquery code is probably the fastest way to achieve what you want with minimal changes to other html/css. Just stick the following code in a *document ready* function and change the few bits of css as stated below.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 200){
        $('anchor3').css({
            "margin-top": "80px"
        })
        $('icon').css({
            "margin-top": "10px"
        })
        $('oldurl').css({
            "margin-top": "296px"
        })
    }
    else{
        $('anchor3').css({
            "margin-top": 300 - $(window).scrollTop()
        })
        $('icon').css({
            "margin-top": 230 - $(window).scrollTop()
        })
        $('oldurl').css({
            "margin-top": 516 - $(window).scrollTop()
        })
    }    
})
```

You need to change the CSS for **a3text** to make `margin-top:60px`, remove the `position` and `margin-left` attributes, then add `display: block`

Ideally, you would just have `icon`, `anchor3`, and `oldurl` inside one container `div` so that you could just use jquery on the container rather than the three items individually!

But this ought to get you what you're after (tested on the live tumblr site with  FF Scratchpad).

**UPDATE (2)**

Launch firefox and go to the page: http://thatoneguyoveryonder.tumblr.com/ then open scratchpad (SHIFT + F4) copy/paste the following code and press CTRL+L. It should then say something (in scratchpad) like `/* [object Object] */` If that happens scroll down the webpage and watch the magic happen - if this is what you're after I'll explain implementing it for you :)

```
$('#sidebar').css({
    position:'fixed',
    top:410,
    left:700 + 60 + (($(window).width()-940) / 2),
    "z-index":900
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 370){
        $('#sidebar').css({
            top: '30px'
        })
    }
    else{
        $('#sidebar').css({
            top: 410 - $(window).scrollTop()
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: That caused it to be fixed in the middle of the page.

Comment: Yeah, you can move it around by changing the `top` and `margin` attributes. You need to use javascript to get it start in the middle of the page and then move to the top..

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to a JS Fiddle which (I believe) demonstrates what you're after.

Comment: http://snipt.org/AGff7  Ok so since i have about no idea what I'm doing, here is the code im working with. In case you are not familiar with the layout, the custom CSS is at the end of <style>

Comment: And yes that was what im loking for.

Comment: Okay, so is this [link](http://baelor.tumblr.com) the actual page? If so, you then want to have the mini-profile type thing on the left scroll and then stay on the page?

Comment: I've added another update to my answer with the jquery to make this work for you! Just place the code in a _document ready function_ and you're away (not forgetting the quick changes to the *a3text* css

Comment: did i mention that i dont know what im doing?

Comment: I think you may have mentioned that! No problem though, I'll try and keep things as step-by-step as possible. Check out my update above and things should be working the way you want them to :)

Comment: I took the background off and when i scroll, the background changes to white at the top and black in the middle. I also changed top '30px' to 57. Other than that, its perfect!

Comment: No problem. I take from that that you managed to get it working the way you wanted to?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the colouring problem... The reason it goes black/white is because the `.fixed` class has a `background` css attribute. If you don't want it to be black and white remove the `background` from `.fixed`

Comment: I took out everything that i put in dealing with the background and it still messes up.

Comment: I got it to work! What i did is i put it in <head> at first but then i just moved it to where the rest of the stuff for the sidebar was and the color fixed!

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
position:fixed
```

Here is a jsfiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/aBaNM/ , even if you scroll the body, red div should be positioned there.

Comment: Click ask a question and scroll down to see what i mean. Ive already tried fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, position:fixed with top:0px and left:0px should do it. Be careful using fixed positioning for navigation though, If the user's screen is smaller than the menu, you'll never be able to see the overflow.

Comment: I want it to start in the middle of my page then fixed to the top of the page when I scroll

Comment: I can't think of a css only approach to this but waypoints js ( http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/ ) or skrollr ( https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr ) works well for this. You'd just switch to position fixed when the top of the viewport reaches the top of the element and it should look like it sticks to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for modal layers (for without click), will ignore parent **position: relative;**

```
.layer-without-click-element {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

takes top, left 0 of the window and covers full width and height browser window size,
set **z-index** less than modal.